# how to extract part of a string using php,i am using it in codeigniter

Tags: php, string

I am having string output

```
string 'TxnDate ValueDate   Description RefNo./ChequeNo.    BranchCode  Debit   Credit  Balance' (length=78)
string '12-Aug-11   12-Aug-11   TOTRANSFER-INBTAXRETERNJULY--   CT55544242TRANSFERTO3055555593Mr.ANILKUMARYG/985252.
```

I want to get the string after the string 'TxnDate',like this

```
 ValueDate  Description RefNo./ChequeNo.    BranchCode  Debit   Credit  Balance'
'12-Aug-11  12-Aug-11   TOTRANSFER-INBTAXRETERNJULY--   CT55544242TRANSFERTO3055555593Mr.ANILKUMARYG/985252 ."12,300.00" 500.00 1,00,194.98'
```

Comment: Can you post your original string @anju

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = "TxnDate ValueDate   Description RefNo./ChequeNo.    BranchCode  Debit   Credit  Balance' (length=78) 12-Aug-11   12-Aug-11   TOTRANSFER-INBTAXRETERNJULY--   CT55544242TRANSFERTO3055555593Mr.ANILKUMARYG/985252";    
$whatIWant = substr($data, strpos($data, "TxnDate") + 1);    
echo $whatIWant;
```

Comment: i want to get the part of the string starting  from 'valuedate'

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not fully clear to me, but you can try with PHP `explode()` function. You need to do merge two strings in one then explode the string separated by "TxnDate".

```
$merged_string = "TxnDate ValueDate   Description RefNo./ChequeNo.    BranchCode  Debit   Credit  Balance' (length=78) 12-Aug-11   12-Aug-11   TOTRANSFER-INBTAXRETERNJULY--   CT55544242TRANSFERTO3055555593Mr.ANILKUMARYG/985252";    
$str_array = explode("TxnDate", $merged_string);
echo $str_array[1];
```